# Find the remaining months in a year

Tags: java, date

I am trying to find a way to get an `array` of month for a year(Ex:`2017`)

2. The array to be the remaining months in a year only
3. Is this possible, What is the best way to achieve this
4. I searched for the answer couldn't find it

ex:{"`October`","`November`","`December`"}

---

**What I have done so far:** I am able to get current year

```
Date now = new Date();    
int year = now.getYear();
```

Comment: The current month is maybe more useful than the current year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better use new API `LocalDate` rather than `Date`, it's easier to use

- first, you need to get the current `date` **:** *here it's 07/10/201*
- you need to find out many month there is until the end of the year **:** *here it's 2*
- then you create an `array` of the `size + 1` (+1 is for current month) **:** *here size is 3*
- then you fill the `array` with the month of date you have + `i` month

---

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
int nbMonthRemain = 12 - date.getMonth().getValue();

String[] monthsRemaining = new String[nbMonthRemain + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < monthsRemaining.length; i++) {
    monthsRemaining[i] = date.plusMonths(i).getMonth().toString();
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(monthsRemaining)); // [OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER]
```

---

Tips :

Replace `.toString()` by **:**

- `.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);` to get `[October, November, December]`
- `.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE, Locale.ENGLISH);` to get `[10, 11, 12]`
- `.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);` to get `[Oct, Nov, Dec]`
- ...

Comment: Good! You could also use the `YearMonth` class, as the day is not important to the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GregorianCalendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)` to get current month number (For oct you will get 9)

Answer (score 0):

```
 i believe something like below code could help      

import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
public List GetLeftMonth(Integer Mon_num){
 List<String> monthsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] months = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
        for (int i = Mon_num; i < months.length; i++) {
          String month = months[i];
          System.out.println("month = " + month);
          monthsList .add(months[i]);
                }
    return monthsList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
  int currentMonth = now.getMonthValue();
  int monthsInAYear = 12;

  int monthsRemaining = monthsInAYear - currentMonth;
  System.out.println(monthsRemaining); // 2

  for (int i = currentMonth; i <= monthsInAYear; i++) {
    System.out.println(getMonthName(i)); // OCTOBER NOVEMBER DECEMBER
  }
}

private static Month getMonthName(int monthValue) {
  return Month.of(monthValue);
}
```

Don't forget to import `import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;`

As already said, don't use `java.util.Date` but `java.time.LocalDate` instead, since it is (arguably) easier to work with.